# Store resource IDs in database?

Tags: android, translation, android-room

Imagine a database table with different food items, e.g. milk. I want the product names to be translated. I want to keep the translations separate from the table and use string resources instead. So my table might look like this:

```
ID product_name stringRes
1  milk         ???
```

In my app I have `@string/milk` for the translations. How would I store a reference to `@string/milk` in the database? `R.id.milk` is likely not always the same ID value on different compilations, so putting ? R.id.milk` in the table isn't a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Store your own identifier in the database, and have code in your app to map that identifier to its text representation. Today, that text representation might come from a resource. Next month, it might come from a translation that you download. A month after that, it might come from an label supplied by the user.

Comment: Well, but if I have 1000 products, I need a large when statement or a large hashset or so.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: Quite possibly. There is nothing stopping you from having your identifier be the string representation of a resource name (e.g., `milk`), then using `getIdentifier()` on `Resources` to look up a translation. However, that still gives you the flexibility to change text representation lookup strategies to something else if/when the need arises.

Comment: thanks, I like the idea with `getIdentifier()`. Any idea how performant that is compared to storing the translations in a second table (like androCoder's answer)? Thinking about queries returning 100 rows.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: `getIdentifier()` uses reflection, so it's not the sort of thing to do in a tight loop, and maintaining a cache would be good if it is reasonably convenient. Having translations in the database is fine, if you want to go that route, but your question indicated that you wanted to use string resources for now, so I did not really consider it. A database join is probably slower than an in-memory reflection lookup, just because it does more disk I/O, but that is just an educated guess, not the result of actual testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Resource ids are not always same. So, it is not a good idea to refer db column by resource id. Then, for the translation, ideally you should never prepackage the translation if you have dynamic products/items. So for referencing back to the database, ideally you should have a different table where you can map translation like this:

```
id | product_fk | translated_name | translated_source_iso
```